# Using MATCH, AGAINST multiple times in MySQL fulltext search

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, full-text-search, order-by

I'm using MySQL database for my e-commerce project.
And here is my query for search:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.name, p.price, p.created_at,
    MATCH(p.name)   AGAINST('Sony* xperia* FHD* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as Prv,  
    MATCH(b.name)   AGAINST('Sony* xperia* FHD* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as Brv,   
    MATCH(bm.name)  AGAINST('Sony* xperia* FHD* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as BMrv,  
    MATCH(o.name)   AGAINST('Sony* xperia* FHD* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as Orv,
    MATCH(ov.name)  AGAINST('Sony* xperia* FHD* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as OVrv
FROM products p 
    LEFT JOIN brands b          ON  b.id = p.brand_id                     AND MATCH(b.name)  AGAINST('Sony* xperia* FHD* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    LEFT JOIN brand_models bm   ON  bm.id = p.brand_model_id              AND MATCH(bm.name) AGAINST('Sony* xperia* FHD* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    LEFT JOIN options o         ON  o.product_type_id = p.product_type_id AND MATCH(o.name)  AGAINST('Sony* xperia* FHD* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    LEFT JOIN product_option_values pov ON  pov.product_id = p.id 
    LEFT JOIN option_values ov  ON  ov.id = pov.option_value_id           AND MATCH(ov.name) AGAINST('Sony* xperia* FHD* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
WHERE   
    (MATCH(p.name) AGAINST('Sony* xperia* FHD*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  
    OR MATCH(b.name) AGAINST('Sony* xperia* FHD*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  
    OR MATCH(bm.name) AGAINST('Sony* xperia* FHD*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  
    OR MATCH(o.name) AGAINST('Sony* xperia* FHD*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    OR MATCH(ov.name) AGAINST('Sony* xperia* FHD*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
    AND 
    COALESCE(b.id, bm.id, o.id, ov.id, pov.id) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    p.id
ORDER BY 
    ((Prv*100) + Brv + BMrv + Orv + OVrv) DESC, p.updated_at DESC;
```

Here I used MATCH, AGAINST 3 times. First in SELECT for relevance. Second in JOIN and third time in WHERE.

1) Can usage MATCH, AGAINST multiple times affect to speed?

2) If yes, how can I change my code to get same result and reduce speed?

Comment: 1) Specify your MySQL version. 2) MATCH ... AGAINST in WHERE clause seems to be excess - all records from tested tables which do not match are already ejected by join condition.

Comment: 1) mysql.exe Ver 8.0.12 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL). 2) ok, i got it. So now using MATCH ... AGAINST 2 times. Is that ok?!

Comment: And which one will be best to use MATCH ... AGAINST in join or in WHERE clause?

Comment: MySQL version allows you to try MATCH .. AGAINST filtering in CTE and joining in main query. I think the condition selectivity is good enough for filtered recordset to be compact. *in join or in WHERE clause?* In join only, or the logic will be changed.

Comment: @Akina. Thanks for your response. How can I select an answer?!

Comment: Create the final query variant and post it as self-answer. This can be useful to other participants with a similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main performance problem comes from `OR` between multiple tables, then from the need to check for rows from each table.

**Plan A**:

One common improvement is to turn `OR` into `UNION`, but it may be only a partial solution.  See how far you can get with this query (which will become a subquery in the real query):

```
SELECT p.id, MATCH(b...) AS Brv
      FROM brands b        JOIN products p ON b.id = p.brand_id
      WHERE MATCH(b...)
UNION ALL
SELECT p.id, MATCH(bm...) AS BMrv
      FROM brand_models bm JOIN products p ON bm.id = p.brand_model_id
      WHERE MATCH(bm...)
...
```

That query should be reasonably fast because each subquery can efficiently use the `FULLTEXT` index that (*I assume*) exists in `brands`, etc.  Also, you must have `INDEX(brand_id)`, `INDEX(brand_model_id)`, etc.

Once that looks good (and fast), the rest will be even messier, but fast.

**Plan B**:

This is possibly better in the long run, but it requires setup.

Build a single table with all the text columns into 5 columns (with a single `FULLTEXT` index on all 5).  Or, you could build a single text column with all the text combined from the other columns.  By having a single column (with `FULLTEXT`), the test will be faster, and avoid the need for `OR` or `Coalesce`.

That table would have a copy of `p.id`, thereby allowing you to quickly reach into the 5 tables to get the 5 individual `MATCHes` (if not already gotten) and do the `ORDER BY` computation.

**Plan C:**

This might be best.  Noticing the format of

```
((Prv*100) + Brv + BMrv + Orv + OVrv)
```

Do like Plan B, but with 2 text columns -- one for `p.name`, one for the combination of the other 4 tables.  You get `Prv` from the `MATCH` on one column, and you get (approximately) `Brv + BMrv + Orv + OVrv` from the other text column.

**Plan D:**

Hmmm... This may be even simpler?  Have an extra table with `p.id`, `name`, source (products, brands, etc) and a "weight" (100 or 1).  Then a simple query against this table gets virtually all the data needed (except for p.name, p.price, p.created_at).  Then `JOIN` to `products` to get those 3 columns.

Comment: thank you a lot. But I'm new in SQL queries. And to be fair I don't understand your Plan D. And little confused if I understand plan A. I like Plan B and Plan C. But it will look like denormalization of my database. Will it take much time in index'ing that table for every update? And I'm thinking of adding another `synonyms` column for each `name` column. It will be something like `tags`.

Comment: I thought about joining all in one table. But there are two problems. 1) What if user selects specific brands or models?. I'll have to use brands ids in with `OR`. But i can add `id` of brand or model to 'new table' as `brand_id`. Then I can use this table without joining tables.  2) This is a biggest problem. Tables `options`, `option_values` and `product_option_values`. If user selects specific options values. Like screen_size  = FHD or HD or just all available sizes. I think I'll have to use `JOIN` with `OR`. What do you think, @Rick James?

Comment: @SDeaV - The Search will be the toughest problem you need to solve.  Put aside the concepts of brands, options, etc, and focus on "what will the user want to search on?" and "How can I keep that simple and efficient?"  Putting all the likely names, tags, model numbers, etc, into a single table with a single FULLTEXT index is probably the best.

Comment: @SDeaV - Indexes are automatically updated as you do updates/inserts/deletes.  Just create the index and don't worry about it.

Comment: And one last question @RickJames. I did something like Plan C. I can get relevance of two `colums` seperately. But what I can use in `WHERE` clause? Should I use `OR` or there is somethin that i can do?

Comment: @SDeaV - My Plans do not preserve your formula _exactly_, but they have _similar_ effect.